Laravel GET Route Calling Wrong Class Function
I'm learning Laravel on an existing 11.29.0 project.
I have two routes defined:
//api.php

Route::get('/items/approved', [ItemController::class, 'approved']);

Route::get('/items/{id}', [ItemController::class, 'show']);

In my controller I have this:
//ItemController.php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\AnonymousResourceCollection;
use App\Http\Resources\ItemResource;

class ItemController extends Controller{

  //MARK: Approved
  public function approved(): AnonymousResourceCollection
  {
    error_log('inside approved');

    //...
  }

  //MARK: Show
  public function show($id): ItemResource|JsonResponse
  {
    error_log('inside show');
    
    //...
  }
}


When I do a GET request to /items/approved it always hits the show($id) function.
Shouldn't the fact that /items/approved comes before /items/{id} make it so the approved() function is called? What am I missing?

Try to clear cached routes with php artisan route:clear.

Turns out this was the issue! My clearing the route cache (which I didn't know existed) I can get it to work even with /items/approved when there's an /items/{id} route after it. Thanks!

I am glad it worked for you. And that is right, if you have dynamically created routes always put statically created routes above since parser when reads [routes.php] file stops as soon as finds fitting one - as you witnessed yourself.

@Tpojka If you want to add your response as an answer below, I can mark it as the accepted one.

When ever issue with routes pops up, several commands in terminal can narrow investigation
# 1. check registered routes for identifying route in subject
php artisan route:list

# 2. clear already cached routes
php artisan route:clear

Sometimes (at least in older versions of Laravel), even any php artisan command can not be executed giving the error, for example adding new artisan command class. To update PHP's autoloader file, first execute
composer du

Then artisan command will execute quite.
Docs about artisan route commands.


The {id} route parameter in /items/{id} is a wildcard that will match ANY string in that position. Even approved also falls under this.

You can try these

Wildcard
Grouping
naming routes.


Route::get('/items/{id}', [ItemController::class, 'show'])->where('id', '[0-9]+');


Route::prefix('items')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/approved', [ItemController::class, 'approved']);
    Route::get('/{id}', [ItemController::class, 'show']);
});


Route::get('/items/approved', [ItemController::class, 'approved'])->name('items.approved');


The Reason is laravel is treating both as same, for example if you send a request
http://127.0.0.1:8000/items/approved
http://127.0.0.1:8000/items/1232
Technically it should work as expected but due to laravel wildcard it look for but Laravel interprets {id} in /items/{id} as a wildcard parameter that can match any value, including the string approved. As a result, the /items/{id} route matches the request /items/approved before Laravel has a chance to match it against the /items/approved route.
Route::get('/items/approved', [ItemController::class, 'approved']);
Route::get('/items/{id}', [ItemController::class, 'show']);

How to fix:
Laravel routes are evaluated top-down, but more generic routes like {id} can override specific ones if their patterns are not restricted.
The where() method allows you to fine-tune what a route parameter can match.
Example
Route::get('/items/approved', function(){
  return 'Item approved';  
});
Route::get('/items/{id}',function(){
    return 'Item id';
})->where('id', '[0-9]+');


This happens because both the routes are same and Laravel could not make difference between
'/items/approved'

and
'/items/{id}'

since "approved" and "{id}" are same endpoints.
If you enter same path twice (or more) the last one will replace all the above.
Fix : Just change the route paths like
'items-approved'

and
'items/{id}'

You can see it works as expected!

Hmm... when I use Route::get('/items-approved', [ItemController::class, 'approved']); on my route, I get a 404 error.
